# ngAnimate delays ng-if fadeouts

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am using ngAnimate for some animation. However, if I include the module in my app, then all the `ng-if`s also get delayed, which I obviously do not want that.

I include this module as `anguular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);` and then use `$animate.enter(...)` somewhere in one of my factories.

Then in another directive, I have an `ng-if="something"` and everytime `something` changes, I can see a delay before the div is removed. I inspected the DOMs and I could clearly see an `ng-animate ng-leave` classes being added. When I remove `ngAnimate` module, everything works just fine.

There is also no `.ng-leave` or `.ng-enter` that would act globally (i.e. I use them as `.myDiv.ng-leave` and such)

Can someone enlighten me?

**EDIT**

Alright, so I figured that I could use `$animate.enabled()` to turn it off on a specific controller. So right now, in my directive's controller, I just do:

```
controller: function($scope, $element) {
    $animate.enabled(false, $element);
}
```

But what if I needed to use `$animate` on something specific within this `$element`? Why is `$animate` becoming globally active on every damn transition without me specifically asking it?